# Using if statement for excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 3 data columns written as text and I want to output some text based on their condition using if statement
Ex)

If right end letter of column 1 is “a” and left letter of column 2 is “b” the output should be “c” and if left end letter of column 1 is “d” and left letter of column 2 is “e” the output should be “f”

I have tried if statement with AND but somehow the code does not run and I need help!

Comment: =if(and(right(a1,1)="a",left(b1,1)="b"),"c","do next test") so you can expand as needed. But you could use the and() and drive a vlookup with a table.

Answer (score 2):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=CONCAT(XLOOKUP(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(2,,1,LEN(A1)-1),1)&LEFT(B1),{"ab","de"},{"c","d"},""))
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can work with this:

[image]

Formula in cell C2:
IF(AND(RIGHT(A2,1)=F2,LEFT(B2,1)=G2),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,1),$F$2:$H$6,3,0),"")

So if the and returns true the vlookup finds and returns the letter.