# Excel Spreadsheet Formula to check multiple conditions using IF, AND OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm an excel formula newbie and I needed some help getting my head around writing a complex formula. It checks multiple columns to mark a user as being on or offsite in column[af]

I have tried to write this out contextually, hoping it makes sense. square brackets refers to the columns that are being checked [af] is the column where the result is outputted

```
If [AG]=”P” or “V-ZVG” or “V-NUK” or “APP 2” or “ SD”, then  [AF] = COMPLIANT,  
AND IF [X] = Onsite AND  [Y]  does Not = “STAFF “ then = [AF] COMPLIANT
AND IF [X]”Offsite” AND [Y] “SE” OR "SU" OR "DE"  then [AF] =COMPLIANT 
AND IF [Y] N/A or “0” then [AF]= COMPLIANT 
AND IF [X] “offsite” AND [Y] “ONSITE-EXT” or “EXT OP” Then [AF]= NON COMPLIANT
```

Is there a way to combine multiple IF, AND, OR ,statements on just a few columns. I have tried to watch some video tutorials on youtube but not been able to apply this to my scenario.

is it possible to write one long formula that will checks for all the above conditions and reports a result in 'AF'

im not sure if I should be using AND / OR

any guidance  will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show some sample data then expected output. What is your excel version? `IFS()` function may simply your current long formula.

Comment: I would create helper columns for each check. Furthermore it is always a good idea to put the conditions (e.g. P, V-ZVG, V-NUK etc) in an extra table and to check against that table. If your boss wants you to change the conditions, you only need to change the table values not the formula

Comment: Provide an actual formula that you have created, along with multiple rows of sample data and the expected results. You may then receive more constructive comments and possibly an answer.

Comment: Have a look at this for a worked example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72910863/4961700